# condition.wait_for intellisense error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm doing a simple tutorial based around threads. In this exercise I am supposed to get threads to wait for each other.
I have copied the example code verbatim with the exception that I'm not using `namespace std;` and am instead writing in `std::`each time I need it.

The error in question corresponds to the line:

`if (condition.wait_for(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mut), std::chrono::seconds(3)))`

Intellisense tells me that "the expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)" but I looked up the documentation on `condition.wait_for` and it can return `std::cv_status::timeout`, `std::cv_status::no_timeout` as well as `true` and `false`. When I go to build, it thinks it can only return `std::cv_status`.

It should work right? Does it require the third parameter? The example I'm following doesn't use one.

Comment: There are two different `wait_for` functions. One of them returns `bool` and the other does not. You are calling the one that does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bo says, there are 2 versions of the function. I'm going to assume there was a typo in the example and it meant to use the version of the function with three parameters, here's some working code, I don't know if it works in the same way as the example intended.

`if (condition.wait_for(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mut), std::chrono::seconds(3), [] {return true; }))`